# When I Click Button For Search Data in DataGridView, It Adds What I Want to Search in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview

Like I Said in Header When I Click Button For Search Data in DataGridView, It Adds What I Want to Search in DataGridView

**Code:**

```
    private void mtrTile_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (
            txtBox_TeacherName.TextLength    == 0 |
            txtBox_TeacherSurname.TextLength == 0
            )
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                this,
                "Lütfen Bütün Kutuları Doldurunuz!",
                "UYARI!",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Warning
                );
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TeacherName AS [Öğretmenin Adı], TeacherSurname AS [Öğretmenin Soyadı] FROM Teachers WHERE(TeacherName LIKE '" + txtBox_TeacherName.Text + "')AND (TeacherSurname LIKE '" + txtBox_TeacherSurname.Text + "')", con);
                sda.Fill(ds);
                DGV_Teachers.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                con.Close();

                MessageBox.Show(
                    err.ToString(),
                    "HATA!",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error
                    );
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Normally Like This**

[image: Normally Like This]

---

**After Clicking Button Five Times**

[image: After Clicking Button Five Times]

Comment: Provide your complete source code, you may have added some where else in aspx file or might be calling your add functionality instead of search functionality.

Comment: @anilshrestha I am not using asp.net and i provided complete source code

Comment: Can you provide the source which is invoking this method: void mtrTile_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) ?? Or please provide frontend portion for search if any.

Comment: @anilshrestha when i click button this method invoking

Comment: After this completion do it invoke any other methods? I suggest you to keep you all source code for resolving the issue sooner. You are making solving time lengthier.

Comment: Most possible error is the you might not have cleared your data grid value after each search. Clearing your datagrid before DGV_Teachers.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; might be the solutions.

Comment: @anilshrestha I tried but none of them worked.

Comment: I have added an answer below. Hope those works out well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you define the DataSet `ds`? Did you declare it as a global variable? Try to declare it as a local variable in the method.

Here is my test code and everything works fine.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"connection string"))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Movie", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds, "t1");
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["t1"];
    }
}


private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"connection string"))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select* From Movie Where Title=@Title", conn);
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", textBox1.Text);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: I finally fix the error, couse of error is actually if i set dataset as a global it adds datagridview's rows what I want to search

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the connection, try using:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

Or,

```
 DGV_Teachers.DataSource = null;
    DGV_Teachers.DataBind();
```

Or,

```
DGV_Teachers.Rows.Clear();
DGV_Teachers.Refresh();
```

Or,

```
dt.Rows.Clear();
```

Comment: first one didn't worked but second one give me a error and error says "This List Cannot Be Cleared"

Comment: Made some changes in first one and added third one. Please refer this may work out.

Comment: visual studio says " 'DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' " for DGV_Teachers.DataBind();